# "She doing X and me doing Y" or "her doing x and me doing Y?"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

What's the correct construction?

Example sentence:

> We sat silently in front of each other, she covering her belly and me covering my pants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, it's a question of subject or object.

The possibilities are illustrated:

*She doing X and I/my doing Y* did not take my fancy. (Subject)

Mum suggested *her doing X and me/my doing Y*. (Object)

Your example sentence uses the popular *me* rather than the formal *I*.

The latter, which is *more* correct, would read:

*We sat silently in front of each other, she (was) covering her belly and I (was) covering my pants.*

Answer (score 1):

**An easy way to remember if you should use subject pronoun** (I/you/he/she/it/etc.) **or object pronoun** (me/you/him/her/etc.) **is to see the location of the verb**

[this works for easier sentences, as the sentences become more complex this becomes more difficult to decipher]

**Subject pronouns go before a verb** and **an object pronoun goes after a verb.**